# BOOL issue in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

When I'm trying to do this to get the BOOL from a dictionary, I get:

```
BOOL isTrue = [someDict objectForKey: @"isTrue"];
```

I get:

```
Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

I set the dictionary by doing this:

```
self.someDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
    initWithObjectsAndKeys:
        self.isTrue, @"isTrue",
        nil];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
BOOL isTrue = [[someDict objectForKey:@"isTrue"] boolValue];
```

The only way to store a `BOOL` in an `NSDictionary` is to box it in an `NSNumber` object.  A `BOOL` is primitive, and a dictionary only holds objects.

Similarly, to store a `BOOL` in a dictionary, use:

```
[someDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isTrue] forKey:@"isTrue"];
```

EDIT: (in response to a comment)

There are two ways of representing this as an `@property`.  One is to declare the ivar as a `BOOL`, and the other is to declare it as an `NSNumber`.

For the first case, the ivar is:  `BOOL isTrue;`, and the property is `@property BOOL isTrue;` (I'm ignoring naming conventions, obviously).

For the `NSNumber`, the ivar is: `NSNumber * isTrue;` and the property is `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isTrue;`.  If you go with this route, you might want to provide a second setter method (`setIsTrueBool` or something) that allows you to just pass in `YES` or `NO`, and then you do the boxing yourself.  Otherwise anyone who calls this would have to do the boxing themselves.

I'd personally most likely go with option #1, but it really depends on what the class's purpose was.

Comment: how would the @property look?

I have @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isTrue;