# How to get double value from dictionary?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get a double value from a dictionary. How can I accomplish this in objective-c?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Dave's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067361/bool-issue-in-objective-c/2067372#2067372) to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067361/bool-issue-in-objective-c) holds true for this, as well.  To store a double value in an NSDictionary, you will need to box it in an NSNumber.

To set a double value in the dictionary, you'd use code like the following:

```
[someDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:yourDouble] forKey:@"yourDouble"];
```

and read it back using the following:

```
double isTrue = [[someDict objectForKey:@"yourDouble"] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Brad Larson's response is exactly right. To elaborate on this a little more, you have to explicitly "wrap up" non-object number types (e.g., `int`, `unsigned int`, `double`, `float`,  `BOOL`, etc.) into `NSNumber` when working with anything that expects an object.

On the other hand, however, some mechanisms in Objective-C, like Key-Value Coding (KVC), will automatically do this wrapping for you.

For example, if you have a `@property` of type `int` called `intProperty`, and you call `NSObject (NSKeyValueCoding)`'s `valueForKey:` method like `[ someObject valueForKey:@"intProperty" ]`, the return result will be an `NSNumber *`, NOT an `int`.

Frankly, I don't care for having to switch between dealing with object and non-object types (especially `struct`s and `enum`s!) in Objective-C. I'd rather everything be treated as an object, but maybe that's just me. :)